# class GoogleMapView and javaFX

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2

i'm try a write a simple javafx program using the GmapsFX. this is the code that i copied from internet for learn the main rudiments of this library.

this is the file .fxml

```
<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <GoogleMapView fx:id="mapView" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Map" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="376.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

this is the controller:

```
package application;

import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;   
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.InfoWindow;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.InfoWindowOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.Marker;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MarkerOptions;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class SampleController implements  MapComponentInitializedListener {

    @FXML
    private GoogleMapView mapView;

    private GoogleMap map = null;

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {

        MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();
        LatLong latLong = new LatLong(47.6097, -122.3331);
        mapOptions.center(latLong)
            .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
            .overviewMapControl(false)
            .panControl(false)
            .rotateControl(false)
            .scaleControl(false)
            .streetViewControl(false)
            .zoomControl(false)
            .zoom(12);

        map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLong);
        Marker marker = new Marker(markerOptions);
        map.addMarker(marker);

        InfoWindowOptions infoWindowOptions = new InfoWindowOptions();
        infoWindowOptions.content("<h2>ROMA</h2>Location di Roma<br>");
        InfoWindow infoWindow = new InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        assert mapView != null : "fx:id=\"mapView\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";

        mapView.addMapInializedListener(this);      
    }
}
```

and the answer from eclipse is:
1866 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called

is there anyone that can help me, please

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Have you tried debugging it to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: i would to see a map, with at the center the value of the coordinates, like Google Maps, with all the google maps  commands. i don't know, but i believe that is possible.